Why will Direct referencing not work for accessing another workbook
I am trying to access data in another workbook (say "W-1.xlsx", "W-2.xlsx", "W-3.xlsx",...) using the below formula
="'["&B2&".xlsx]Sheet1'!$E$3"

In B2 i have given W-1, W-2, W-3.
If, 
='[W-1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E$3

works perfectly fine, Why the above formula does not?
Why is it not working and what can i do to make it work. I want to access the file using the text in cell which is the file name and I want to do it without VBA.

You need INDIRECT, but note that the other workbook must be open.

I will suggest in using Power Query or may be VBA to pull the data in the required sheet and use the same to make other formulas. Using direct referencing or INDIRECT() usually tends to break and returns error often. Personally, I avoid using such type of variations. if i have no options I use them.
